# How to fix: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Tags: 404-error, directory

I'm using azure as a hosting service and I tried to create a new virtual directory for my subdomain.
So I created a folder in my ftp then I created directory in below image
[image]

Then I've edited my web.config file But unfortunately I got this error `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` So I deleted the directory and restored web.config to oldest but didn't worked. I've googled and I think the error that I got because of permalinks. But I didn't changed anything. So what is the problem please help web site not working only showing the error

Comment: That's an Azure error message not a WP one, is there a WordPress install in that folder though? It's not enough to create an empty web host account and get space, you have to fill that space with WP and run the installer

Answer (score 4):

**Caveat**
I know this question is a little out of date and our question/issue is technically regarding an [Azure Wordpress Resource](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-host-a-scalable-and-optimized-wordpress-for-azure-in-minutes/) not a hosted environment... but I thought it might be helpful to answer for future readers.

**Background/Issue**
We spun up an *Azure Worpress resource* and migrated our site to it using [updraft](https://updraftplus.com/). Once transferred and browsing the site we had the same issue:
`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

**Solution**
[Tom](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell) mentioned above that it's an Azure issue. And looking further in, it's more specifically it ended up being an IIS `web.config` issue. Here are steps we took to correct it:

**Getting to the web.config file**

1. In the Azure portal go to the wordpress resource and then to *Advanced Tools*:

   [image: Azure Portal Wordpress Resource Navigation]
2. Once we got to the Kudu interface we navigated to the *Debug console* -> *PowerShell* (or *CMD* if you prefer). Then navigated to the root wordpress directory where the `web.config` lives:

   [image: Kudu PowerShell directory view]

**Editing the web.config file**

1. After opening it up the problem was pretty obvious. Somehow Azure spun up the wordpress resource without adding the correct rewrite rules. Or maybe our updraft transfer overwrote it...

   [image: The culprit! A blank web.config file]
2. So we just added the appropriate rewrite rules. (for an *azure wordpress resource*)

   [image: New web.config rewrite rules]

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <configuration>
         <system.webServer>
           <rewrite>
             <rules>
               <rule name="WordPress: http://your-azure-site.azurewebsites.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                 <match url="*"/>
                 <conditions>
                   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                 </conditions>
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
               </rule>
             </rules>
           </rewrite>
         </system.webServer>
       </configuration>
   ```
3. Save it!

Once we saved it the wordpress pretty permalinks worked as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by replacing the default web site configuration with my own site configuration

Comment: You mean the web.config, like Ryan's answer? Did your version look like his?